# Switching maps from 2D to 3D in iOS in Map Mode Satellite/Hybrid

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to switch Maps from 2D mode to 3D mode when the map mode is Satellite/Hybrid. same as iPhone Maps Apps from Apple. for that i am doing the below coding. please check and let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
MKMapCamera *camera1 = [MKMapCamera cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate:contactLocation fromEyeCoordinate:userLocation eyeAltitude:200.0];
[camera1 setPitch:0]; // for 2D mode when maps switch to 2D mode
[camera1 setPitch:50]; // for 3D mode when maps switch to 3D mode
[_mapView SetCamera:camera1];
```

Please Note: Now the points the above Code only works when Map type is Standard. The above solution is not working with Map Type Satellite/Hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `pitchEnabled` property on the MKMapView to YES. Otherwise the MKMapView always renders in 2D as if the camera is looking straight down, regardless of how you set up your camera.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What is `contactLocation` and what s `fromEyeCoordinate`?  You need to be a little more specific. Not to mention you have `SetCamera:` instead of `setCamera:`...

Comment: Nope Contact Location and fromEyrCoordinate is not a problem. The Real Problem is When Switching 2D/3D with the Map Modes Satellite/Hybrid Mode.Still not Working. I am just editing my question again.please see updated questions.